# Set a lookup field using Plugin in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

How to Set a value for lookup field using Plugin in Dynamics CRM?
I am using the code below but it is NOT working.

```cs
Entity ent = (Entity)service.Retrieve("mdoc_sentence", sGUID, new ColumnSet(new string[]{ "lookupFiled"} );

ent["lookupFiled"] = "baa25488-6d99-es11-99da-225056836fb7";

service.Update(ent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use following code:

```cs
ent["lookupfield"] = new EntityReference("entityname", new Guid("baa25488-6d99-es11-99da-225056836fb7"));
```