# Set Lookup field in dynamics using C# Edited now

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

I have getSet Entity, there I have a form on which I have created a field of lookup type, I need to set and get its value in the same form, left side of lookup field will get value and that value will be set on the right side of the form, kindly have a look to the attached image as well.
here is the attachment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAQ68.png)

Here is my code

```
 if (entGetSet.Contains("new_getlookup"))
                {
                    lookup = ((EntityReference)entGetSet["new_getlookup"]).Id.ToString();
                    entGetSet["new_getlookup"] = new EntityReference("new_getlookup", new Guid(lookup));
                }
```

Comment: you are fetching same lookup filed and trying to set the same lookup field. `new_getlookup`. Also where did you updated your entity? what error are you getting, write your complete code and error

Comment: i had already set it here is the code ' entGetSet["new_setlookup"] = new EntityReference("new_getlookup", new Guid(lookup)); ' and i'm getting error of Key

Comment: That is the error I'm facing right now may be logical name missing. The entity with a name = 'new_getlookup' with namemapping = 'Logical' was not found in the MetadataCache.

Comment: new_getlookup probably is not the logicalname of the field you are trying to set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a lookup field using Plugin in Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894391/set-a-lookup-field-using-plugin-in-dynamics-crm)

Comment: @Guido Preite, that's the name i checked it

Comment: @Arun Vinoth, no that answerndoesn't satisfied my question

Comment: 1. Understand the attached answer. 2. Understand the syntax. 3. Understand your environment entity names, attribute names. Then everything will work :)

Comment: @Arun Vinoth, dear that answer is only setting value statically for the lookup field

Comment: @AzamKhan if you don't mind post a screenshot with the column definition where we can see the logicalname

Comment: @Guido_Pretie, yeah sure it's in the question I already attached it there